# How to write a DELETE query with WHERE conditions using JDatabaseQuery syntax?

Tags: mysql, joomla-4

I have a query which I am trying to convert to JDatabaseQuery syntax, but I'm not able to find the correct way.

The query is the following:

```
DELETE upt FROM #__mycomponent_user_posts AS upt WHERE upt.posts=0 AND upt.owner=0 AND upt.favorite=0 AND upt.subscribed=0 AND upt.params=''
```

With JDatabaseQuery, I'm only able to obtain the following query with nothing between DELETE and FROM:

```
DELETE FROM #__mycomponent_user_posts AS upt WHERE upt.posts=0 AND upt.owner=0 AND upt.favorite=0 AND upt.subscribed=0 AND upt.params=''
```

How to obtain the correct query with JDatabaseQuery?

Comment: Are you certain that is the syntax you want? Doesn't appear it would be valid MySQL syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html.

Are you trying to delete a row or modify the table?

Comment: Hello, In the doc quoted https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html, it says that there are multiple table syntax : `DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]`  `DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    USING table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]`

Comment: But your query isn't using and doesn't need `[LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] ` keywords in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MySQL DELETE query doesn't have a column value between keywords DELETE and FROM.

There is also no benefit to declaring a table alias.

`owner` is a mysql keyword, but not a RESERVED keyword, so it doesn't need to be backtick-wrapped.

```
$db = Factory::getDBO();
try {
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->delete("#__mycomponent_user_posts")
                ->where(["posts + owner + favorite + subscribed = 0",
                         "params = ''"]);
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->execute();
    if (!$affrows = $db->getAffectedRows()) {
        echo "Possible Logic Error - No Qualifying Rows To Delete";
    }
    echo "Success $affrows Deleted Rows";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Syntax Error"; // . "Query: " . $query->dump() . " & Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I am actually taking the liberty to condense your where clause logic using simple mathematics.

I have built in some diagnostic checks for you.  If you want to see the generated query, echo `$query->dump()`. Be sure to never reveal raw mysql errors to the public.

[I am not at home to test my snippet, let me know if I have any mistakes in it so that I can adjust.]

To mirror your original where clause logic...

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->delete("#__mycomponent_user_posts")
            ->where(["posts = 0",
                     "owner = 0",
                     "favorite = 0",
                     "subscribed = 0",
                     "params = ''"]);
```

Comment: Could be wrong, but the `where` clause definitely looks odd.

Comment: How so? Admittedly, I'm taking artustic license.  (I'm not at my joomla computer right now.)

Comment: @user Are you meaning to delete rows of `user_posts` or rows of `users` with no activity? From the outside-looking-in, I feel like you might be trying to prune the dead weight from your users table.  My crystal ball is at home with my Joomla computer, but if this is the case, perhaps the table name needs adjusting.

Comment: I want to delete some entries in the table which have default values

Comment: Then my snippets should work as desired unless you have incorrectly posted the table or column names.  Have you tried it? What was the outcome?

Comment: I tried with our code snippet, it works so it didn't like the alias